# What is the difference between string literals and a pointer?

Tags: c

Generally, you can initialize a pointer with any string literals like `char *str = "Hello"`. I think this means `"Hello"` returns the address of `'H'`. However, the below isn't allowed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[64];
} Student;

Student initialization(char *str) {
    //Student tmp = {}; strcpy(tmp.name, str) //(*1)This is allowed.
    //Student tmp = {"Hello"}; //(*2)This is allowed.
    Student tmp = {str}; //(*3)This is not allowed.
    return tmp;
}

int main(void) {
    (...)
}
```

Could anyone tell me the reason why (*2) is allowed but (*3) is not allowed? Compiling this code makes the error below.

```
warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     Student tmp = {str};
                    ^
```

Comment: It's a quirk in the language. A string literal may be used as an initializer, a pointer to string may not. That's just the way it is.

Comment: The empty brace initializer `= { }` is not allowed in strict standard C, but GCC does allow it as an extension.

Comment: It helps when you note that string literals have type array of char. It makes sense that you can initialize an array with an array, but not with a pointer.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand what I wanted to know. And I'll keep in mind that `= {}` is not strictly correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All these cases you are trying to initialize a `char` array. Now after saying that - we can see it makes thing easier. Just like an `char` array where if we write down a string literal directly it initializes the `char` array with the content of the string literal.

But in the second case, the string literal which is basically a `char` array is converted to a pointer to the first element of it (the fist character of string literal)  which is then used to initialize the `char` array. That will not work. Note that, even if `str` is a pointer to a `char` array which is not a literal this won't work. For the same reason as specified. Standard allows initialization from the string literal directly. Not other way round.

From standard [6.7.9p14](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p14)

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF-8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.

Comment: Thank you. I enriched my understanding of the initialization and now understand what I wanted to know.

Comment: @ynn.: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[What do I do when someone answers my
question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)