# Size of character strings

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

From code below

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *s;
    s="cool man army";  //here LHS and RHS are same type
    printf("ptr= %zd, normal string= %zd",sizeof(s),sizeof("cool man army"));
    return 0;
}
```

`s` is `char *` type and `"cool man army"` is also `char *` then why are outputs`ptr= 8, normal string= 14` different?

Comment: Who told you `"cool man army"` is a pointer? It's `const char [14]`, an array.

Comment: Duplicate candidate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48967078/what-is-the-difference-between-string-literals-and-a-pointer

Comment: @HolyBlackCat what do expect when equate them, they must be of same type.

Comment: This is not always true. E.g. `int x; x = 12.3;` works even though the types of lhs and rhs are different.

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Comment: @beta_meme_beta That’s not even true in *sane* programming languages. In C and C++ implicit conversions are the norm, and “assignable from” in no way implies “has the same type as”.

Comment: Anyway, I’ve removed the C++ tags since this code is invalid C++ and should not compile on a modern compiler — or at least not without warnings.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A string literal is actually an array, not a pointer.  Section 6.4.5p6 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding string literals states:

> In  translation  phase  7,  a  byte  or  code  of  value  zero  is 
>   appended  to  each  multibyte character sequence that results from a
>   string literal or literals.  The multibyte character sequence  is 
>   then  used  to  initialize  an  array  of  static  storage  duration 
>   and  length  just sufficient  to  contain  the  sequence.

So when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the usual decay to a pointer does *not* happen and you get back the size of the array in bytes.

The behavior of array decay into a pointer is documented in section 6.3.2.1p3:

> Except  when  it  is  the  operand  of  the `sizeof` operator, the
>   `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string  literal
>   used  to  initialize  an  array, an expression  that  has type ‘‘array
>   oftype’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ 
>   that  points to  the  initial  element  of  the  array  object  and 
>   is  not  an  lvalue.   If  the  array  object  has register storage
>   class, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: I was wondering why "cool man army" showed behaviours like pointer, but its actually like an array, i got your point.

Comment: @beta_meme_beta: You can read more about arrays decaying to a pointer in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying).

Answer (score 0):

First one is a chars pointer, the second not. You could see it with **typeinfo** header:

```
printf("%s %s", typeid(s).name(), typeid("cool man army").name());
```

And see something like that

```
Pc
A14_c
```

You could see that the second is an array of 14 chars.

Answer (score 0):

First, your code don't compile in C++. You cannot drop const like that when building in c++ mode.

I think the mistake is here:

```
s="cool man army";  //here LHS and RHS are same type
```

They are not the same type. String literals are character array, and those decay into pointers.

The type of the string literal is `char const[14]`. In C++, you can create a reference to it:

```
auto const& ref_to_literal = "cool man army";
assert(sizeof(ref_to_literal) == sizeof("cool man army")); // True!
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the question with both "C" and "C++", I will answer the question for both languages.

The statement

`s = "cool man army";`

where `s` is of type `char *` is only valid in C, not C++. In C++, the variable `s` must be of type `const char *`, because the string literal [decays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) to that type. Only in C does the string literal decay to the type `char *`. However, in both languages, the string literal is read-only, even if it is not `const` in C.

On modern 64-bit platforms, pointers are normally 64-bit, that is why `sizeof(s)` is 8 bytes (which is equivalent to 64 bits). The string literal `"cool man army"` however is an array and not a pointer (and also does not decay to one when used with the `sizeof` operator). Therefore, `sizeof("cool man army")` is the actual length of the array (including the terminating null character), which is 14.

EDIT: Meanwhile, the C++ tag has been removed from the question. However, since it was not the OP who did that, I will not remove my comments about C++ from my answer.